# Usando jQuery, como selecionar elementos com duas classes CSS

Tags: jquery, css, seletores

Tenho uma div que usa duas classes CSS.
Eis o HTML :

```
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box1 destaque"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2 destaque"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```

Quero selecionar a `div` que tenha as classe `box1` e `destaque` (no meu exemplo a segunda div) **apenas**.

O que já tentei :

Se faço : `$('.box1')` seleciono as duas divs com classe `box1`. Não é o que quero.

E se faço : `$('.destaque')` acabo selecionado uma div com `box1` e outra com `box2` (o que não quero)

Já tentei `$('.box1 .destaque')` mas não seleciona nada.

Então como devo montar o seletor jQuery para buscar as divs que usam as classes **box1** e **destaque**?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Tira o espaço:

```
$('.box1.destaque')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2w9x7/

Comment: uhul! Já imaginava que era algo simples. Valeu!

Answer (score 9):

No caso de ser só `div` com `.box1` e `.destaque`:

```
$('div.box1.destaque');
```

Na ordem dos seletores, o primeiro pode ser o elemento desejado, no exemplo `div` em seguida você vai especificar algumas características do elemento:

- `#` para ID
- `.` para classes
- `[]` para atributos, exemplo: `[rel=teste]` seleciona `<div rel="teste">`

No final é possível usar o `:` para pseudo seletores (estado, como `:hover`, `:active`, etc ou primeiro filho, impares, etc)

Quando você adiciona o espaço no seletor, ele identifica que você está querendo ir para o próximo nível, então agora são elementos filhos da caracteristica que você está buscando.

Então `$('.box1 .destaque');` vai achar isso:

```
<div class="box1">
    <div class="destaque"></div> <-- este elemento foi o único selecionado
</div>

<div class="box1 destaque">
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Quando você diz que um elemento tem várias propriedades tanto no [css](/questions/tagged/css) quanto no [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) você insere todos os seletores e pseudo classes juntos

Exemplo:

```
#id.classe1.classe2[atributo=valor] {
    display: inherit;
}
```

O exemplo acima corresponderia a um elemento assim:

```
<span id="id" class="classe1 classe2" atributo="valor">elemento</span>
```

Se você separar por espaço você está procurando um elemento que contém
o outro. 
 Exemplo:

```
#id .classe1 .classe2 [atributo='valor'] {
    display: inherit;
}
```

O exemplo acima corresponderia a um elemento assim:

```
<span id="id">
    <span class="classe1">
        <span class="classe2">
            <span atributo="valor">elemento</span>
        </span>
    </span> 
</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

Ao informar o seletor: `.box1 .destaque` você procura por a classe `.destaque` dentro de `.box1`. Como o elemento que você deseja selecionar possui ambas as classes, o seletor correto é:`.box1.destaque`, que iria retornar:

```
<div class="box1 destaque"></div>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".box2.destaque").html('Class 1');
$(".box1.destaque").html('Class 2');
```

```css
.box1{
  color: red;
}

.box2{
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box1"></div>
<div class="box1 destaque"></div>
<div class="box2"></div>
<div class="box2 destaque"></div>
<div class="box3"></div>
```